# Trans-conductance of the system

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, transconductance

What will be the effective transconductance of the system? We have an amplifier of the voltage gain of -2 and R, C connected as shown. I believe We can't judge if the system is in negative feedback because it is not given here. How to approach?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YghLG.png]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense , a "transconductance" is defined as the ratio between the input voltage and the output current, but your schematic doesn't have an [OUT] node, perhaps you meant the output of the opamp, and the resistor is the external load?
The circuit is a bit like a BJT amplifier, with an emitter resistor of 500R , a collector resistor of 1k, and a 1uf Miller capacitor.  The Miller capoacitor is clearly negative feedback.

Comment: maybe OP means the transimpedance